# Holomorphic Extension of a Sobolev Function is Sobolev

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I would like to start this question with an example that I had in mind. Let $f(x) = (x^2+1)^{-1}$, then we know a few of facts about $f(x)$. Firstly, $f\in L_2(\mathbb{R})$ and secondly, we also know that $f$ is analytic. Thirdly, we can also say that $f\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$, where $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ is a Sobolev Space where the weak partial derivatives up to order $k$ belong to $L_p(\Omega)$.

Then by complex analysis, we can extend $f$ to a holomophic function $g$, namely $g(z) = (z^2+1)^{-1}$ onto a complex strip with upper and lower boundaries of $z= -i+\delta,i-\delta$ for some small $\delta >0$. Furthermore, along this strip $g$ is also in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{C})$ or if you'd like, holding either the real or imaginary part constant in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$.

My question is, if we have an analytic function $f$, that is in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$, can we always find a holomorphic extension $g$ so that holding either the imaginary or real part fixed, $g\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$? (This result is weaker than just saying $g\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{C})$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can we always find a holomorphic extension $g$

Note that by the [identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) such an extension is unique. (Maybe you knew this, but the language of this sentence suggests otherwise.)

> holding either the imaginary or real part fixed, $g\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb R)$.

The example you gave has this property for fixed imaginary part $y$ only when $y\notin \pm 1$, and for constant real part $x$ only when $x\ne 0$.

But it can get worse. Take 
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{c_n}{(x-z_n)(x-\overline z_n)} \tag1$$ 
where $z_n=n^2+i/n^2$ and the numbers $c_n>0$ are made sufficiently small so that the series (1) converges in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb R)$. The series (1) converges locally uniformly on an open set containing $\mathbb R$, namely $U=\{z:|\operatorname{Im}z|<\min(1,1/|\operatorname{Re}z|)\}$. Therefore, $f$ is real-analytic on $\mathbb R$. However, it does not have a holomorphic extension to any strip of the form $\{z:|\operatorname{Im}z|<\delta\}$, due to the presence of poles.

And it can get worse still. As before, let  $U=\{z:|\operatorname{Im}z|<\min(1,1/|\operatorname{Re}z|)\}$. Let $\Phi$ be a conformal map of $U$ onto a Jordan domain bounded by a nowhere differentiable curve. Then $\Phi$ is bounded and analytic on $\mathbb R$, but does not have holomorphic or even meromorphic extension to any domain properly containing $U$. The function $\exp(-z^2)\Phi(z)$ is in $L^2(\mathbb R)\cap L^1(\mathbb R)$. Let $F$ be its antiderivative; note that $F$ is bounded on $\mathbb R$. Finally, let $f(z)=\exp(-z^2)F(z)$. It is easy to check that $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb R$ and belongs to $W^{1,2}(\mathbb R)$. However, it does not have a  meromorphic extension to any domain properly containing $U$. So, the question of integrals along lines is moot: we don't have a function to integrate along lines.